# Why createPool hang-up connection?

Tags: node.js

My terminal hang-up with rows result. why it not release the connection? i know i can do with end method. but end method is for release all connection. how to release currently connection or i missundestand how to use pool connection.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const options =
{
    'host'              : '127.0.0.1',
    'port'              : 3306,
    'user'              : 'pandora',
    'password'          : 'pandora',
    'database'          : 'pandora',
    'supportBigNumbers' : true,
    'waitForConnections': true,
    'connectionLimit'   : 10,
    'queueLimit'        : 10
};

const pool = mysql.createPool(options); 

pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
    // Do something with the connection
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM media', (err, rows, fields) => {
        console.log(rows);
    });
    // Don't forget to release the connection when finished!
    pool.releaseConnection(conn);
 })
```

Comment: conn.query is async

Comment: what its mean? i know it async. but why it hangup the connection. whereas database already return result rows in console.

Comment: even my express route hangup connection. route keep loading in browser. each refresh route, it output in console. but router keep loading.